Can I tape and mud over joints in drywall that have had spackle applied previously?
First time doing major drywall repair. I didnt do my research and thought that I could use drydex spackle to cover the joints. As you can imagine, after three coats and a lot of sanding, the joints look terrible, and most have cracked. Can I sand these joints down smooth and start over with tape and mud? Does the spackle need to come completely off? It is walls and ceiling
If it helps in answering at all, this room was a DIY add on to a garage from the previous owner. None of the studs for walls or ceiling were plumb, straight, or even set a consistent on center dimension. I reused a lot of drywall (which I have since learned was a big mistake) and I think part of my issues are stemming from that unevenness, mix new and old drywall, and lack of experience. Any advice is appreciated.

A pic of your situation would help determine what you can do.

Of course. I meant to do that before and got busy. I'll post something later today. Thanks for responding.
